# Alarm Manager in android does not issue notification on time

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-notifications

i am trying to make a small project in android for the college where the user has the option to select time from time picker dialog and based on the time selected an notification to drink water will be issued to the user and repeated every 15 minutes.However the alarm manager used issues notification vaguely.Sometimes notification are issued on time and repeated after every 15 minutes although after midnight the notifications stop.Also sometimes there is a delay to issue the notification.Cant figure out why! Help appreciated..Here are the necessary xml and java files 
activity_water.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/relative"
    tools:context="com.example.priyam.databaselogin.Water">
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp">
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/reminderWaterCheckbox"
            android:buttonTint="@color/red"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:text="Remind me once at"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="170dp"
            android:text="09:30 AM"
            android:textColor="@color/red"
            android:id="@+id/textViewTime"/>


    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

water.java

```
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class Water extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
TextView time;
    CheckBox waterReminder;
    int h,m;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_water);
        setTitle("Water Reminder");
        getId();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"this",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
private void getId(){
    time=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewTime);
    waterReminder=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.reminderWaterCheckbox);
    time.setOnClickListener(this);
}
private void showDialog(){
    TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                      int minute) {

                    h=hourOfDay;
                    m=minute;


                    Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
                    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,h);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,m);
                    Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Notification_receiver.class);
                    PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),100,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                    AlarmManager alarmManager= (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES,pendingIntent);
                    time.setText(h+":"+m);






                }
            }, h, m, false);
    timePickerDialog.show();



}
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        showDialog();
    }


}
```

Notification_receiver.java

```
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;



public class Notification_receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        NotificationManager notificationManager= (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent intent1=new Intent(context,DashBoard.class);
        intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(context,100,intent1,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                .setContentTitle("Hitfit")
                .setContentText("Its time you gulped a glass of water!Stay hydrated,stay fit!")
                .setAutoCancel(true);
        builder.setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000});
        Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        builder.setSound(alarmSound);
        notificationManager.notify(100,builder.build());
    }

    }
```

Minnimum sdkVersion used is 18

Stuck on this since days.Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the documentation of [`AlarmManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)), you can see the following notice :

> Note: as of API 19, all repeating alarms are inexact. If your application needs precise delivery times then it must use one-time exact alarms, rescheduling each time as described above. Legacy applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to have all of their alarms, including repeating alarms, treated as exact.

I think you are in this case actually, and your alarms aren't exact because that's how the system keeps battery as of API 19.

Comment: Ya but that means before API 19 setRepeating method should work right? My app has API level 18 still it does not schedule notifications on time

Comment: minSdk is not the API you should look into, the behaviour depends on the actual sdk version in the smartphone